# Deserializing Unity Mixed mode into YAML

Tags: unity, unity-ui

is there a way to deserialize `.unity` and `ProjectSettings` file in binary format down to yaml? I provide an example of one of such files below: despite the fact that I see some properties and binary data, it is unclear to me where an object starts and ends, and to identify whether the attributes are children or siblings. Thanks

"G.. .>......

0000-02a0:  10 01 38 00-00 00 d6 01-00 00 07 00-00 00 00 00  ..8..... ........

0000-02b0:  00 00 37 00-00 80 c5 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 80  ..7..... ........

0000-02c0:  00 00 01 00-01 00 a6 03-00 80 b2 01-00 80 04 00  ........ ........

0000-02d0:  00 00 01 00-00 00 01 00-00 00 01 00-01 00 4c 00  ........ ......L.

0000-02e0:  00 80 0f 00-00 00 01 00-00 00 02 00-00 00 00 40  ........ .......@

0000-02f0:  00 00 01 00-01 00 56 00-00 80 15 00-00 00 10 00  ......V. ........

0000-0300:  00 00 03 00-00 00 00 00-20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00  ........ ........

0000-0310:  00 80 20 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 01 00  ........ ........

0000-0320:  20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00-00 80 22 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ..".....

0000-0330:  00 00 05 00-00 00 01 00-20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00  ........ ........

0000-0340:  00 80 24 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 06 00-00 00 01 00  ..$..... ........

0000-0350:  20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00-00 80 26 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ..&.....

0000-0360:  00 00 07 00-00 00 01 00-20 00 01 00-01 00 de 00  ........ ........

0000-0370:  00 80 28 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 08 00-00 00 00 00  ..(..... ........

0000-0380:  00 00 01 00-01 00 a1 00-00 80 32 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ..2.....

0000-0390:  00 00 09 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 01 00-01 00 a1 00  ........ ........

0000-03a0:  00 80 3f 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 0a 00-00 00 00 00  ..?..... ........

0000-03b0:  00 00 01 00-01 00 a1 00-00 80 50 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ..P.....

0000-03c0:  00 00 0b 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 01 00-01 00 56 00  ........ ......V.

0000-03d0:  00 80 5f 00-00 00 10 00-00 00 0c 00-00 00 00 00  .._..... ........

0000-03e0:  20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00-00 80 20 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ........

0000-03f0:  00 00 0d 00-00 00 01 00-20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00  ........ ........

0000-0400:  00 80 22 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 0e 00-00 00 01 00  .."..... ........

0000-0410:  20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00-00 80 24 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ..$.....

0000-0420:  00 00 0f 00-00 00 01 00-20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00  ........ ........

0000-0430:  00 80 26 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 10 00-00 00 01 00  ..&..... ........

0000-0440:  20 00 01 00-01 00 56 00-00 80 71 00-00 00 10 00  ......V. ..q.....

0000-0450:  00 00 11 00-00 00 00 00-20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00  ........ ........

0000-0460:  00 80 20 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 12 00-00 00 01 00  ........ ........

0000-0470:  20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00-00 80 22 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ..".....

0000-0480:  00 00 13 00-00 00 01 00-20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00  ........ ........

0000-0490:  00 80 24 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 14 00-00 00 01 00  ..$..... ........

0000-04a0:  20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00-00 80 26 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ..&.....

0000-04b0:  00 00 15 00-00 00 01 00-20 00 01 00-01 00 56 00  ........ ......V.

0000-04c0:  00 80 87 00-00 00 10 00-00 00 16 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ........

0000-04d0:  20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00-00 80 20 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ........

0000-04e0:  00 00 17 00-00 00 01 00-20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00  ........ ........

0000-04f0:  00 80 22 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 18 00-00 00 01 00  .."..... ........

0000-0500:  20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00-00 80 24 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ..$.....

0000-0510:  00 00 19 00-00 00 01 00-20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00  ........ ........

0000-0520:  00 80 26 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 1a 00-00 00 01 00  ..&..... ........

0000-0530:  20 00 01 00-01 00 a1 00-00 80 9c 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ........

0000-0540:  00 00 1b 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 01 00-01 00 de 00  ........ ........

0000-0550:  00 80 af 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 1c 00-00 00 00 40  ........ .......@

0000-0560:  00 00 01 00-01 00 45 02-00 80 bd 00-00 00 0c 00  ......E. ........

0000-0570:  00 00 1d 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 01 00-02 00 de 00  ........ ........

0000-0580:  00 80 ce 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 1e 00-00 00 01 00  ........ ........

0000-0590:  00 00 01 00-02 00 2e 03-00 80 d7 00-00 00 08 00  ........ ........

0000-05a0:  00 00 1f 00-00 00 01 00-00 00 01 00-01 00 a1 00  ........ ........

0000-05b0:  00 80 e0 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 20 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ........

0000-05c0:  00 00 01 00-01 00 a1 00-00 80 ef 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ........

0000-05d0:  00 00 21 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 01 00-01 00 a1 00  ..!..... ........

0000-05e0:  00 80 ff 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 22 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ..".....

0000-05f0:  00 00 01 00-01 00 be 02-00 80 10 01-00 00 0c 00  ........ ........

0000-0600:  00 00 23 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 01 00-02 00 de 00  ..#..... ........

0000-0610:  00 80 ce 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 24 00-00 00 01 00  ........ ..$.....

0000-0620:  00 00 01 00-02 00 2e 03-00 80 d7 00-00 00 08 00  ........ ........

0000-0630:  00 00 25 00-00 00 01 00-00 00 01 00-01 00 be 02  ..%..... ........

0000-0640:  00 80 1e 01-00 00 0c 00-00 00 26 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ..&.....

0000-0650:  00 00 01 00-02 00 de 00-00 80 ce 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ........

0000-0660:  00 00 27 00-00 00 01 00-00 00 01 00-02 00 2e 03  ..'..... ........

0000-0670:  00 80 d7 00-00 00 08 00-00 00 28 00-00 00 01 00  ........ ..(.....

0000-0680:  00 00 01 00-01 00 de 00-00 80 2b 01-00 00 04 00  ........ ..+.....

0000-0690:  00 00 29 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 01 00-01 00 de 00  ..)..... ........

0000-06a0:  00 80 43 01-00 00 04 00-00 00 2a 00-00 00 00 00  ..C..... ..*.....

0000-06b0:  00 00 01 00-01 00 de 00-00 80 61 01-00 00 04 00  ........ ..a.....

0000-06c0:  00 00 2b 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 01 00-01 00 a1 00  ..+..... ........

0000-06d0:  00 80 75 01-00 00 04 00-00 00 2c 00-00 00 00 00  ..u..... ..,.....

0000-06e0:  00 00 01 00-01 00 8b 01-00 00 99 01-00 00 0c 00  ........ ........

0000-06f0:  00 00 2d 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 01 00-02 00 de 00  ..-..... ........

0000-0700:  00 80 ce 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 2e 00-00 00 01 00  ........ ........

0000-0710:  00 00 01 00-02 00 2e 03-00 80 d7 00-00 00 08 00  ........ ........

0000-0720:  00 00 2f 00-00 00 01 00-00 00 01 00-01 00 ac 01  ../..... ........

0000-0730:  00 00 b8 01-00 00 0c 00-00 00 30 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ..0.....

0000-0740:  00 00 01 00-02 00 de 00-00 80 ce 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ........

0000-0750:  00 00 31 00-00 00 01 00-00 00 01 00-02 00 2e 03  ..1..... ........

0000-0760:  00 80 d7 00-00 00 08 00-00 00 32 00-00 00 01 00  ........ ..2.....

0000-0770:  00 00 01 00-01 00 56 00-00 80 be 01-00 00 10 00  ......V. ........

0000-0780:  00 00 33 00-00 00 00 00-20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00  ..3..... ........

0000-0790:  00 80 20 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 34 00-00 00 01 00  ........ ..4.....

0000-07a0:  20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00-00 80 22 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ..".....

0000-07b0:  00 00 35 00-00 00 01 00-20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00  ..5..... ........

0000-07c0:  00 80 24 00-00 00 04 00-00 00 36 00-00 00 01 00  ..$..... ..6.....

0000-07d0:  20 00 01 00-02 00 a1 00-00 80 26 00-00 00 04 00  ........ ..&.....

0000-07e0:  00 00 37 00-00 00 01 00-20 00 52 65-6e 64 65 72  ..7..... ..Render

0000-07f0:  53 65 74 74-69 6e 67 73-00 6d 5f 46-6f 67 00 6d  Settings .m_Fog.m

0000-0800:  5f 46 6f 67-43 6f 6c 6f-72 00 72 00-67 00 62 00  _FogColo r.r.g.b.

0000-0810:  61 00 6d 5f-46 6f 67 4d-6f 64 65 00-6d 5f 46 6f  a.m_FogM ode.m_Fo

0000-0820:  67 44 65 6e-73 69 74 79-00 6d 5f 4c-69 6e 65 61  gDensity .m_Linea

0000-0830:  72 46 6f 67-53 74 61 72-74 00 6d 5f-4c 69 6e 65  rFogStar t.m_Line

0000-0840:  61 72 46 6f-67 45 6e 64-00 6d 5f 41-6d 62 69 65  arFogEnd .m_Ambie

0000-0850:  6e 74 53 6b-79 43 6f 6c-6f 72 00 6d-5f 41 6d 62  ntSkyCol or.m_Amb

0000-0860:  69 65 6e 74-45 71 75 61-74 6f 72 43-6f 6c 6f 72  ientEqua torColor

0000-0870:  00 6d 5f 41-6d 62 69 65-6e 74 47 72-6f 75 6e 64  .m_Ambie ntGround

0000-0880:  43 6f 6c 6f-72 00 6d 5f-41 6d 62 69-65 6e 74 49  Color.m_ AmbientI

0000-0890:  6e 74 65 6e-73 69 74 79-00 6d 5f 41-6d 62 69 65  ntensity .m_Ambie

0000-08a0:  6e 74 4d 6f-64 65 00 6d-5f 53 6b 79-62 6f 78 4d  ntMode.m _SkyboxM

0000-08b0:  61 74 65 72-69 61 6c 00-6d 5f 46 69-6c 65 49 44  aterial. m_FileID

0000-08c0:  00 6d 5f 50-61 74 68 49-44 00 6d 5f-48 61 6c 6f  .m_PathI D.m_Halo

0000-08d0:  53 74 72 65-6e 67 74 68-00 6d 5f 46-6c 61 72 65  Strength .m_Flare

0000-08e0:  53 74 72 65-6e 67 74 68-00 6d 5f 46-6c 61 72 65  Strength .m_Flare

0000-08f0:  46 61 64 65-53 70 65 65-64 00 6d 5f-48 61 6c 6f  FadeSpee d.m_Halo

0000-0900:  54 65 78 74-75 72 65 00-6d 5f 53 70-6f 74 43 6f  Texture. m_SpotCo

0000-0910:  6f 6b 69 65-00 6d 5f 44-65 66 61 75-6c 74 52 65  okie.m_D efaultRe

0000-0920:  66 6c 65 63-74 69 6f 6e-4d 6f 64 65-00 6d 5f 44  flection Mode.m_D

0000-0930:  65 66 61 75-6c 74 52 65-66 6c 65 63-74 69 6f 6e  efaultRe flection

0000-0940:  52 65 73 6f-6c 75 74 69-6f 6e 00 6d-5f 52 65 66  Resoluti on.m_Ref

0000-0950:  6c 65 63 74-69 6f 6e 42-6f 75 6e 63-65 73 00 6d  lectionB ounces.m

0000-0960:  5f 52 65 66-6c 65 63 74-69 6f 6e 49-6e 74 65 6e  _Reflect ionInten

0000-0970:  73 69 74 79-00 50 50 74-72 3c 43 75-62 65 6d 61  sity.PPt r<Cubema

0000-0980:  70 3e 00 6d-5f 43 75 73-74 6f 6d 52-65 66 6c 65  p>.m_Cus tomRefle

0000-0990:  63 74 69 6f-6e 00 50 50-74 72 3c 4c-69 67 68 74  ction.PP tr<Light

0000-09a0:  3e 00 6d 5f-53 75 6e 00-6d 5f 49 6e-64 69 72 65  >.m_Sun. m_Indire

0000-09b0:  63 74 53 70-65 63 75 6c-61 72 43 6f-6c 6f 72 00  ctSpecul arColor.

0000-09c0:  9d 00 00 00-00 ff ff 90-d0 fe 2f 8b-4a 24 57 e3  ........ ../.J$W.

0000-09d0:  60 5b 9d b4-79 01 22 23-00 00 00 9d-02 00 00 07  `[..y."# ........

0000-09e0:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 37-00 00 80 6b-00 00 00 00  .......7 ...k....

0000-09f0:  00 00 00 00-80 00 00 01-00 01 00 a6-03 00 80 b2  ........ ........

0000-0a00:  01 00 80 04-00 00 00 01-00 00 00 01-00 00 00 01  ........ ........

0000-0a10:  00 01 00 de-00 00 80 11-00 00 00 04-00 00 00 02  ........ ........

0000-0a20:  00 00 00 00-40 00 00 02-00 01 00 22-00 00 00 2d  ....@... ..."...-

0000-0a30:  00 00 00 16-00 00 00 03-00 00 00 00-80 00 00 01  ........ ........

[The file continues, but was truncated tue to space limitations]

Comment: If this is a game for which you have access to the source, you can trivially change the asset serialization mode to force text to get the YAML directly. If it is not a game for which you have access to the source, then it's not clear that you have a licence to modify it in this way, and users here may be understandably reluctant to help you breach the terms of the licence you may hold. 

Comment: I cannot understand why knowing how my own data is serislised might imply a break of my own license... next time I suppose I'll go for a FOSS game engine. Still, even if I change the setup, the files on the ProjectSettings are still in a binary format, just the standard assets are changed to YAML.

Comment: Plus, this would like saying "I have a compiler but I cannot check if the binary contains something more thsn just my code", that is a reasonable question if you ask me!

Comment: Help us understand the application here then. Since Unity provides a built-in method to save .unity files and project settings assets as YAML (and I've just tested this - we can get  both of these in text format rather than binary format just by setting the Asset Serialization Mode to "Force Text"), for what purpose would we need to write a separate converter/parser?

Comment: This does not apply to me, that I'm still seeing the ProjectSettings in binary.

Comment: I'll just go and analyse the binary for myself if noone knows/wants to answer the question, thank you so much for the help. https://youtu.be/IbDAmvUwo5c

Comment: I think you can get answers here if you take a little time to edit your question and explain your application. StackExchange is not just a vending machine for free coding help — it's a collaboration between those asking and answering. So sometimes you need to put in a little extra work so that strangers here — who initially know nothing about your project — can properly understand your application and help you find appropriate solutions for it.